# Usar un formulario que se renderice en todas las páginas de symfony

Tags: symfony4

Me gustaría usar un formulario en todas las páginas que se rendericen de la web. La idea es incluirlo en la etiqueta `header`. Para ello estoy siguiendo la documentación que ofrece la propia página de [Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html)

El caso explican cómo reutilizar estos formularios en distintos controladores, pero no de cómo implementarlo en la plantilla base de CSS, es decir, en `base.html.twig`

El formulario lo he creado dentro de la carpeta Form de esta forma:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class BusquedaType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('Nombre', TextType::class)
            ->add('Correo', TextType::class)
            ->add('Password', TextType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Enviar formulario'))
            ->getForm();
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            // Configure your form options here

        ]);
    }
}
```

donde `Usuario()` es una entidad definida de esta forma:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UsuarioRepository")
 */
class Usuario
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $correo;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNombre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function setNombre(string $nombre): self
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCorreo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->correo;
    }

    public function setCorreo(string $correo): self
    {
        $this->correo = $correo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

La única opción que veo para conseguir tener el formulario en todas las páginas es llamarlo en cada controlador:

```
$usuario = new Usuario();
$form = $this->createForm(BusquedaType::class, $usuario);
```

Comment: Veo dos soluciones: 1. Llamar desde el template un controlador. Para ello puedes revisar: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html 2. Usar carga asíncrona de Javascript, de modo que `header` se carga la primera vez con el formulario, y todo el contenido y lógica del sitio web, lo hace a través de ajax. Para ello, sugiero usar jquery: https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: Creo que lo que tu buscas es añadir bloques `https://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/bundles/block/create_your_own_blocks.html`.
Sonata block bundle te provee de una serie helpers de twig, y te ayuda a definir ciertos controladores (para el bock). En tu caso, tendrias que hacer uno propio (para manejar el formulario). Echa un vistazo, es interesante

Answer (score 0):

puedes crear un servicio e inyectarlo después en el controller para que no tengas que repetir mucho codigo, pero efectivamente tienes que inyectarlo en todas las paginas donde quieras que aparezca e formulario.

```php
class EmailService
{
    /**
     * @var MailerInterface
     */
    protected $mailer;

    /**
     * EmailService constructor.
     * @param MailerInterface $mailer
     */
    public function __construct(MailerInterface $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    /**
     * @param $from
     * @param $to
     * @param $subject
     * @param $template
     * @param $parameters
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportExceptionInterface
     */
    public function send($from, $to, $subject, $template, $parameters): void
    {
        $email = (new TemplatedEmail())
                ->from($from)
                ->to($to)
                ->subject($subject)
                ->htmlTemplate($template)
                ->context($parameters)
            ;
            
        // pour envoyer l'Email
        $this->mailer->send($email);
    }
}
```